# Am I able to set up a code where I can have two ways of turning something on?

Tags: arduino-uno, code-review

I am pretty new to Arduino.

I've created a code with the help of many YouTube tutorials to control a servo with a button. I decided it has gotten a little un-exciting so I've been trying to add a sound sensor module to it so that if you clap or whatever, it will control the servo in the same way the servo did. Is it possible to control the servo with the button *and* the sound sensor so that I have to ways of turning on the servo at the same instance.

The code I currently have just runs the servo constantly and does not stop, you'll probably see what I mean when I attach the code below.
I'm just looking for help on this issue as I don't have a lot of experience with this, but my guess is it is not possible.

```cpp
    #include <Servo.h>;

    const int buttonPin = 8;
    int soundSensor = 2;
    Servo servo;

    int buttonState = 0;

    void setup()
    {
      servo.attach(3);
      servo.write(80);

      pinMode(buttonPin, INPUT);

      pinMode (soundSensor, INPUT);
    }


    void loop() {
      int statusSensor = digitalRead (soundSensor);

      if (statusSensor == 1)
      {
        servo.write(0);
        delay(1000);
        servo.write(180);
        delay(500);
      }
      else
      {
        servo.write(80);
      }

      buttonState = digitalRead(buttonPin);
      if (buttonState == HIGH)
      {
        servo.write(80);
      }
      if (buttonState == LOW)
      {
        servo.write(0);
        delay(1000);
        servo.write(180);
        delay(500);
      }
    }
```

Comment: Yes, you can. You just have to change your thinking from "The button is being pressed" to "The button has *been* pressed".

Comment: you have to realize that controlling a servo, detecting a button press and detecting sound are all completely separate functions ..... you can have a boolean variable `moveThatServo` .... if the variable has a value `true` then the servo is moved and if it is `false` then the servo stops ..... you can have multiple buttons, some set `moveThatServo` to `true` and some set it to `false` .... you can have a sound detector that sets `moveThatServo` to `true` ...... you can write a timer function that does the same..... just use your imagination

Answer (score 1):

Just cobled this together,
untested but should give you some hints in the right direction.

In the main loop it checks the condition of the button and also the sound detector.
If either are active it sets a bool to true.
at the end of the loop, if either are true it calls the servo function that then powers the servo.
hopefully you will be able to pull this apart to add more triggers

```
#include <Servo.h>;

const int buttonPin = 8;
int soundSensor = 2;
Servo servo;

int buttonState = 0;
int statusSensor = 0;

bool runServo = false;  // bool setting to start the servo

void setup()
{
  servo.attach(3);
  servo.write(80);

  pinMode(buttonPin, INPUT);
  pinMode (soundSensor, INPUT);
}

void loop() {
  statusSensor = digitalRead (soundSensor);
  buttonState = digitalRead(buttonPin);

    runServo = false;  // start of loop reset the runServo flag

  if (statusSensor == 1)
  {
    runServo = true;
  }

  if (buttonState == HIGH)
  {
    runServo = true
  }

  if (runServo == true)
  {
    servoFunction();//call the servoFunction code
  }

};


void servoFunction(){
    servo.write(0);
    delay(1000);
    servo.write(180);
    delay(500);

}
```

Spriggsy